# SASS Mixin with optional and variable parameters

Tags: css, sass, mixins

Is there a way to use both optional and variable elements in a sass mixin?

i try

```
@mixin name($className,  $centered: false, $dimension...)
```

but the first dimension value is assigned to `$centered`

switching parameters order don't compile

```
@mixin name($className, $dimension..., $centered: false )
```

the error is:

```
SASSInvalid CSS after "..., $dimension...": expected ")", was ", $centered: fa..."
```

since the mixin without the optional parameter is used in many place (over 70) i dont want yo change it all to add the new parameters, so i want to leave it optional?

Any way to change this mixin or i have to leave the original without `$centered` and create an ovverride with the new parameter?

for info this is the mixin body:

```
    @for $i from 1 through length($dimension){                              
        @if($centered) {
            .#{$className}Td#{$i}, .#{$className}Th#{$i}  { 
                width: nth($dimension, $i); 
                text-align:center;
            }
        }
        @else{
            .#{$className}Td#{$i}, .#{$className}Th#{$i} {width: nth($dimension, $i); }
        }
    }
```

EDIT with complete cowking example:

simply iam defining css for column width of my table in a faster way, so this

@include nome("columnsName", 40%, 30%, 30%);

is rendered in that way:

```
.columnsNameTd1, .columnsNameTh1{width: 40%;}

.columnsNameTd2, .columnsNameTh2{ width: 30%; }

.columnsNameTd3, .columnsNameTh3{ width: 30%;}
```

i want a way to text-align center all my columns, maybe can be interesting see if there is a way do to specify what column to center, making all other left by default

Comment: you got a comma `,` after `$centered: false` in your second mixin.. cuz this should work. otherwise you could try `@if($centered == true)` although this should work without it

Comment: comma was a copy-paste error, i add the compilation error, basically seem he don't want anything after $dimension...

Comment: you could try removing your argslist (`...`), maybe this will kill the compiliing process. but i assume you need more than 1 variable for a dimension :(

Comment: yes, usage i want is: `@include nome("className", 4%, 4%, 4%, 6%, 70%, 12%, true);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do what you're asking because variable arguments (the `...` syntax) **absolutely must be last**.  You have 2 options, I recommend option #2.

Option 1 (examine the last element to see if it is a boolean):

```
@mixin name($className, $dimension...) {
    $last: nth($dimension, length($dimension));
    $centered: if(type-of($last) == bool, $last, false);
    $length: if(type-of($last) == bool, length($dimension) - 1, length($dimension));

    @for $i from 1 through $length {
        .#{$className}Td#{$i}, .#{$className}Th#{$i} {
            width: nth($dimension, $i);
            @if($centered) {
                text-align: center;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Option 2 (use the `@content` directive):

```
@mixin name($className, $dimension...) {
    @for $i from 1 through length($dimension) {
        .#{$className}Td#{$i}, .#{$className}Th#{$i} {
            width: nth($dimension, $i);
            @content;
        }
    }
}

// usage
@include name(rar, 10%, 20%, 30%);

@include name(rar, 10%, 20%, 30%) {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: see my edit: real purpose of mixin is to create the class name by itself

Comment: @gt.guybrush How does this not do what you're asking?

Comment: i see previous version, this Option2 is great, never see before @content. now i will try to search a version where can set text-align of every columns

Answer (score 2):

ok, what if you try testing the last value of your list, since it seems that sass does not support anything else after a list as a parameter.

```
@function last($list) {
  @return nth($list, length($list));
}
//returns the last item of a list

@mixin nome($className, $dimension...) {
    @for $i from 1 through length($dimension){
        @if(last($dimension) == true) {
            .#{$className}Td#{$i}, .#{$className}Th#{$i}  {
                width: nth($dimension, $i);
                text-align:center;
            }
        }
        @else{
            .#{$className}Td#{$i}, .#{$className}Th#{$i} {width: nth($dimension, $i); }
        }
    }
}
```

so if you add `@include nome("className", 4%, 4%, 4%, 6%, 70%, 12%, true);` and the last value is `true` it should center your div, or whatever you trying to do!

Comment: if done with `@for $i from 1 through length($dimension) - 1` works but dont link it very much since the variable (dimension) become something other.

Answer (score 1):

This *is* actually possible using something Sass calls [Arbitrary Keyword Arguments](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin/#taking-arbitrary-keyword-arguments). The idea is that you pass a keyword argument as one of your arbitrary (variable) arguments, and then extract it from the argument list using the [`meta.keywords($args)`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/meta/#keywords) function.

Here's a simplified version of your code to illustrate how it works:

```
@use "sass:map";
@use "sass:meta";

@mixin name($class-name, $widths...) {
    $centered: map.get(meta.keywords($widths), centered) or false;
    $i: 1;
    @each $width in $widths {
        .#{$class-name}-#{$i} {
            width: $width;
            @if $centered {
                text-align: center;
            }
        }
        $i: $i + 1;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
@include name("column", 40%, 30%, 30%);
// .column-1 {width: 40%;}
// .column-2 {width: 30%;}
// .column-3 {width: 30%;}

@include name("column", 40%, 30%, 30%, $centered: true);
// .column-1 {width: 40%; text-align: center;}
// .column-2 {width: 30%; text-align: center;}
// .column-3 {width: 30%; text-align: center;}
```

The magic happens in that second line of the mixin, where you set the value of `$centered`. As you can see, the keyword argument is also removed from `$widths`. It's a little bit weird (and not widely known?), but very handy!

Comment: cannot try it since i have no more that project but upvote for the idea. thanks